# XPATH con numero incrementable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping

Hola amigos estoy presentando un problema estoy haciendo web Scraping a una web y necesito que un XPATH vaya aumentando para extraer los datos pero al momento de concatenarle el numero que voy aumentando con un ciclo for me da error.

```
for n_dato in range(2,101):

    nombre = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="onu_configured_list"]/table/tbody/tr[' + n_dato + ']/td[3]').text

    print(nombre)
```

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolver el problema usando Format para aumentar el numero conforme al ciclo for:

```
for n_dato in range(1,101):
        nombre = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
            '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[3]'.format(n_dato)
        ).text

        print(nombre)
```